# Strange behaviour between EF 6 and ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a behaviour between EF 6 and my WPF ViewModel, which I don't understand:

My ViewModel has an ObservableCollection Protocols. In the ViewModel's constructor I call

```
Protocols = new ObservableCollection<ProtocolType>(dal.GetAllProtocols());
```

dal is my ProtoColTypeRepository from the DataAccessLayer.

I have a DataGrid in the View, which is bindeded to Protocols. If the DataGrid adds a new item (CanUserAddRows = true) the ProtoColTypeRepository takes notice, so I don't need to call dal.Insert(). Updates are noticed, too.

If I delete an item from the DataGrid by pressing DEL-Key, the 
ProtoColTypeRepository doesn't notice it. At this point I have to call dal.Delete() myself.

How and why takes my ProtoColTypeRepository notice of inserting and updating automatically?

I would expect that I have to call dal.Insert() and dal.Update() manually because the ObservableCollection is for the View and my ProtoColTypeRepository for the DataAccess...

Another strange thing happens if I call a another window from my MainViewModel lets say LanguageViewModel. I have the same constructor call:

```
Languages = new ObservableCollection<ProtocolType>(dal.GetAllLanguages());
```

and also a DataGrid in the view which is binded to Languages. But in this case I have to synchronize my DataAccess manually by calling dal.Insert(), dal.Update() etc.

I really wonder why I don't have the behaviour which I have written further up because it works the same...

I use VS2010

I hope that you can explain me this things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why should your dal know that your ObservableCollection has changed?

Comment: hey WiiMaxx, thats my questions... If I add an item over the DataGrid (view) and call dal.SaveChanges(). The added item is in my database. So for some reason my dal takes notices when the observeableCollection adds a new item...

Comment: I'll start looking at comparing the two classes between the one that you manually need to call Insert and the one that doesn't?

Comment: @GrayFox your dal gets notified when your DB get changed not when you add an item to your `ObservableCollection` because if you only add an item to your Collection nothing will happend in your dal but if you add manually an item in your DB the dal will get notified somehow